# PhpMailer sends mail but message not working

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

This is my html code

```
<form method="post" action="PHPMailer.php" enctype="text/plain">
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)"><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" /></div>
        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)"><input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="12u"><input name="messageInput" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="reset" class="button alt" value="Clear Form" /></li>
                <li><input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    require_once 'xxxxxxxxxxx\phpMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
    $mail->isSMTP();                                 
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;    
    $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'; 
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxx';                      
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';    
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    

    $mail->setFrom('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Mailer'); 
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');       
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');  
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = '$message';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
}
?>
```

I do receive the mail when I remove the "if (isset($_POST['submit']". Can't seem to figure out what Ii've missed out.

I'm trying to retrieve the message from the form and put it as $message, but it keeps telling me unidentified index when i add $message = $_POST['messageInput'];. I'm very new and would love any help i can get. Thanks!

**Edit***
removed enctype and it worked!**

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: `</textarea>` whats that doing in the form?

Comment: `$mail->Body = '$message';` should be `$mail->Body = $message;` since variables aren't expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: it shows array(0) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post will work once you remove `enctype="text/plain">`

Valid values for enctype in  tag are:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
```

for the fuller answer lets include Barmar's comment:

`$mail->Body = '$message';`

should be

`$mail->Body = $message;`

since variables aren't expanded inside single quotes

but you can just use

`$mail->Body =$_POST['messageInput'];`

no need to create a new variable for it

Comment: thank you for this!